# Where is a systemd variable stored?

Tags: linux, systemd

I was reading the `/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service` for `mysql` db and there is the row

```
# Start main service
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS
```

Where is `$MYSQLD_OPTS` stored? I need to check the values.

Comment: What does the rest of the service unit look like? Environment variables typically come from `Environment` or `EnvironmentFile` directives earlier in the unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the value set in the environment of the unit use

```
systemctl show mysqld.service --property=Environment
```

and to find the file where it might be set look through the output of

```
systemctl cat mysqld.service
```

for `Environment=` and `EnvironmentFile=`.
The variable does not necessarily have to be set anywhere, when it is just a place-holder and its value will be empty.